# MetaMask sometimes infinite loading

Tags: web3js, metamask, bug

my MetaMask does sometimes load infinitely.
It then says "Connecting to Main Network" until I click on "Ropsten" and then back to "Main Network". That normally is no problem for me.

But as I am a dApp developer I have no idea how to identify this when a user has this problem. When checking network, it does not define any network. When checking if user is logged in/has an account, it also simply says nothing.

**Is it possible to detect this loading process with web3?**

Comment: How about filiing a bug to MetaMask and trying to get the actual issue resolved?

Comment: Do you also sometimes have the issue?